# Debugging R Packages With Rocker (How to Change Version?)

Tags: r, docker

I'm currently attempting to get Docker set up (with Rocker) to debug a possible memory leak using rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang. I used the following command to run docker:

```
docker run --name=r-devel-ubsan-clang -v (mydir):(mounteddir) --rm -ti rocker/r-devel-ubsan-clang /bin/bash
```

The version of Rdevel that results is: `(2017-09-16 r73288) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"`. Any idea how I can upgrade to a newer Rdevel version? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These containers are no longer build automatically, c.f. https://github.com/rocker-org/r-devel-san/issues/4. You can get the [`Dockerfile`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rocker-org/r-devel-san-clang/master/Dockerfile) from github and build a newer version your self.

BTW, as noted in the [Readme](https://github.com/rocker-org/r-devel-san-clang/blob/master/README.md), you should add `--cap-add SYS_PTRACE` to the command line options.